# DataList loaded dynamically, how to store values inside between postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I am loading a Datalist to create the necessary filters (textbox's,dropdown's,checkbox's) for a grid. So far so good, the problem is between postback's.
I understand that every time a postback occours I need to recreate the Datalist with the items, but how can I store the input made by the user on each control?

Imagine that I have created a textbox for filtering a column and the user input "test" on the textbox and click on button that triggers the event to search the value in the gridview.

How can I use (if so) the "viewstate" and when?

Here is the code

Client code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="imgHelp" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlFilter" runat="server" Width="95%">
                <asp:DataList ID="dlFilter" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemDataBound="dlFilter_ItemDataBound" OnItemCreated="dlFilter_ItemCreated" EnableViewState="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFilterName" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("szFilterName") %>' />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfFilterType" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("szFilterObjType") %>' />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("szFilterFiller") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="middle" style="width: 120px; text-align: right;">
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="7pt" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                                        Text="Search" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
            </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <div id="div1" style="overflow: auto; height: auto; width: 97%;">
            <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" CssClass="tablecloth-theme" Width="97%" GridLines="Vertical"
                AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="gv_PageIndexChanging"
                OnSorting="gv_Sorting" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="Beige" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#7799AF" Font-Bold="True" Height="20px" Font-Names="Verdana"
                    Font-Size="7pt" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField SelectText="Details" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                </Columns>
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="Beige" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Server code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            if (!scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack)
            {
                DataInfo_Load();
            }

            //Page_Prepare();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowError(ex);
        }
    }


    protected void DataInfo_Load()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet_Load();
    Filters_Load();
            Grid_Load();

            if ((int)ViewState["PageStatus"] >= 2)
            {
                if (ViewState["Saveable"] != null)
                    btnNew.Visible = (bool)ViewState["Saveable"];
                else
                    btnNew.Visible = true;
            }
            else
                btnNew.Visible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected void DataSet_Load()
    {
        try
        {
            Connection cn = new Connection();
            DataSet ds = null;
            string Query = hfSelStore.Value;
            SqlCommand SQLcmd = new SqlCommand(Query);
            SQLcmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ds = cn.ExecuteSqlCmd(cn.SqlLocalConn, SQLcmd);
            ViewState["DataSet"] = ds;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected void Filters_Load()
    {
        try
        {
            if (ViewState["DataSet"] == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("No DataSet!");
            }

            DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["DataSet"];

            if (ds == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("DataSet is empty!");
            }

            if (ds.Tables.Count == 5)
            {
                //contains filter
                pnlFilter.Visible = true;
                DataView view = new DataView(ds.Tables[4]);
                view.Sort = "lId";
                dlFilter.DataSource = view;
                dlFilter.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected void dlFilter_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {

                // Retrieve the Label control in the current DataListItem.
                HiddenField hfFilterName = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFilterName");
                HiddenField filtertype = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hfFilterType");
                if (filtertype != null)
                {
                    DataListItem dlt = ((filtertype.Parent) as DataListItem);

                    int itemIndex = dlt.ItemIndex;

                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.ID = "lbl";
                    lbl.Text = hfFilterName.Value;
                    lbl.Attributes.Add("style", "font-size:7pt; color:#005780; font-weight:bold;");

                    Control ctr = Control_Create(filtertype.Value);
                    ctr.ID = "val";

                    dlt.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table><tr><td valign=\"middle\" style=\"width: 120px; text-align: right;\">"));
                    dlt.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    dlt.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td><td>"));
                    dlt.Controls.Add(ctr);
                    dlt.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr></table>"));
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowError(ex);
        }
    }

    protected Control Control_Create(string controlType)
    {
        Control c = new TextBox();
        try
        {
            if (controlType == "TextBox")
                c = new TextBox();
            else if (controlType == "CheckBox")
                c = new CheckBox();
            else if (controlType == "DropDownList")
                c = new DropDownList();
            else if (controlType == "RadioButton")
                c = new RadioButton();
            //else if (controlType == "Checkbox")
            //    c = new TextBox();
            //else if (controlType == "Checkbox")
            //    c = new TextBox();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return c;
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            gv.SelectedIndex = -1;
            gv.PageIndex = 0;

            Grid_Load();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need to load the listview on each postback. The ListView is able to hold the state information during the PostBack. However you should not call the DataBind() function on each postback, if you do so, it will loose the state information. Check where are you binding the ListView

Regarding the dynamic controls added to the ListView, if you add them in the ItemDataBound event as you are doing right now, they retain the state during postback if you call the DataBind() function during first page load i.e under 
if(!IsPostBack) code block.

Another point is avoid creating the controls with html in the codebehind as much as possible. You can add these controls in the ItemTemplate and access them in the code behind. If you want to create multiple controls like a table under the list view, you can add a repeater control in the listview's ItemTemplate and bind the repeater in OnItemDataBound event of the ListView.

As I dont see your complete code like Control_Create function, I cannot assist or show code on how you can use Repeater control inside the ListView.

Comment: Hi Kiran, thanks for your reply however let me say that I am using a DataList and not a ListView. I already using the the !Postback and every time the search button is clicked the postback accours and the items in the DataList disapear. That's why I and forcing the databinding of DataList. And the "Control_Create" is just a function to translate a string into a control (in this case textbox). One more thing this is a "content place holder" I am using ajax with script manager.

Comment: Can you post the ascx code also? Is ViewState enabled?

Comment: Can your replace !scriptManager.IsInAsyncPostBack with !IsPostBack and check?

Comment: No Kiran, is the same.